# How can I lock my rvb script file (Rhino Script)?

Tags: c#, locking, rhino, rhino3d

How Can I lock my rvb script file, I want to open the script without seeing the content.

```
Option Explicit


Call Main()

Sub Main()

    Rhino.Print("Test")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to run a .rvb script without opening the script editor, there are several ways to do this.

Here are some options. All options assume you have saved your script to a local .rvb file.

**Option 1:**

1. Open the .rvb file by double-clicking, this will launch Rhino and run the containing script.

**Option 2:**

1. With Rhino open, run the '*LoadScript*' Command.
2. Click the '*Add...*' button and navigate to your .rvb file in the file browser and click '*open*' once the file is selected. This will add the script to the '*Select a script file to load:*' box.
   [image]
3. Select the newly added script, and click '*Load*'. This will run your script in the current rhino document.

**Option 3:**

1. Remove the `Call Main()` line from the script
2. Make your Sub Method public `public Sub Main()`
3. Save the script as a Main.rvb (I believe the file name and sub method name should match)
4. Tell Rhino to load your script at startup by using the '*options*' command and then navigating to '*RhinoScript>Startup>Script files*' and adding the file path to the .rvb file.
   [image]
5. Add an Alias to run the script as an easy command. This can be done with *Options>Aliases>New*. The '*Alias*' is the command name you would like to have run the script and the '*Command macro*' would be `_-runscript Main`.
6. Type your Alias in the command line to run your script anytime without needing to re-load, view, or change the script.
   [image]

**Locking**
If you mean 'locking' in a more traditional sense of locking a file. I am not familiar with any Rhino options, but in Windows you can right-click the file, open 'Properties', and in the 'General' tab there is a 'Attributes: Read-Only' option, which would lock the file and prevent modification but will not prevent the scrip from being able to run in rhino.